# Can't able to get the value from textbox outside the function

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects

I have a simple JS code that finds the value of textbox that is entered by the user.

```
 var input= document.getElementsByClassName("textbox_properties");
 var click_button=document.getElementsByClassName("button_properties");
 var animal="Platypus";
 var textbox_response=input[0].value;

 function verify_request()
  {
   alert(animal);
   alert(textbox_response);
  }
```

As I have made animal variable in Global scope and that is accessible inside the function but for textbox value it is saying `Undefined` which is strange.
In the console I am getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`

I tried putting this `textbox_response` variable inside the function., it is behaving normally.
I want to know why can't i find the value from textbox outside the function.

Comment: I have linked an external file for Javascript code

Comment: If there's nothing in your input when you assign its value to `textbox_response`, then it's perfectly normal for it to be empty. **EDIT** Regarding the error - try moving your JS code to the bottom of your file, preferably right before closing the body.

Comment: Have you ensured that the code only runs after the document has fully loaded?

Comment: Well i have now put the script line at the bottom of HTML and this time , the alert for textbox_response is blank and  no error in console and also I'm typing the response in the textbox and submitting it using submit button